# pass bean variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am trying to clean up an application which is written in jsp servlet and javascript, jquery. Currently in the jsp's, there are lots of javascripts written. I am trying to move all these javascripts to a separate js file. In the jsp.

```
<%
String firstName= "";

if (sampleBean.getName() != null) {
   firstName = sampleBean.getName();
}
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=loadVal;

  function loadVal() {    
    document.getElementById('business_name').value = "<%=firstName%>";
  }
</script>
```

I need to move this loadVal() to another js file. So how can I pass this "<%=firstName%>" which is fetched from the bean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<%
String firstName= "";
if (sampleBean.getName() != null) {
   firstName = sampleBean.getName();
}
%>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var firstName = <%= firstName %>; // assigning java variable to javascript variable 
</script>
```

Write above code in beginning of your jsp , and move all your js in a separate file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=loadVal;

  function loadVal() {    
    document.getElementById('business_name').value = firstName;
   }
</script>
```

Now you need to make sure that you include that js file after this code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var firstName = <%= firstName %>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this function basically adds the function to be called on window.onload;

You can also use it to add as many functions on onload. Even you can move the startUp function to external js and your loadVal function too can be moved in external js

```
    <%
    String firstName= "";
    if (sampleBean.getName() != null) {
       firstName = sampleBean.getName();
    }
    %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var firstName = <%= firstName %>;
        function startUp(func)
        {
            if(window.onload)
            {
                var ref = window.onload;
                window.onload = function(){

                    ref();
                    func();
                };
            }
            else
            {
                window.onload = func;       
            }
        }

        startUp(function(){ loadVal(firstName);});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you need to refactor your script to make it more modular and configurable.

You can use [the module pattern in JavaScript](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) in order to make this better.

**my-module.js**

```
var MyModule;
(function(MyModule){

   var fName = MyModule.firstName || "";  

   function loadVal() {    
      document.getElementById('business_name').value = firstName;
   }

   window.onload=loadVal;

}(MyModule || (MyModule = {})));
```

And now in your main page you can do something like this. The good thing about this approach is that you don't have to pollute your global scope.

```
<head>

<!-- Other declarations -->

   <script type="text/javascript">

   var MyModule;
   (function(MyModule){

      MyModule.firstName = <%= firstName %>;

   }(MyModule || (MyModule = {})));

   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/scripts/my-module.js">
   </script>
</head>
```